# How to allow crossdomain cookies in chrome 80

Tags: java, google-chrome, jsessionid, samesite

In Chrome 80 updates, the sessionid stored in cookies in Crossdomain is constantly changing because of the samesite option. How can we handle it in a java or server environment?

I look forward to hearing from you. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "constantly changing" here. If you set the appropriate `SameSite` attribute, e.g. `SameSite=None; Secure` only for when you **need** cross-site cookies then that value only changes when your server changes it.